# How to prevent bots from running with knifes at the start of each round in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm playing `aim_warehouse` map vs bots using Standard game mode. But bots rush with knifes towards me for the first 5 seconds of each round. After 5 seconds they switch to rifles. There's no point in switching to knifes because the map is very small.

How do I stop them from rushing with knifes and use rifles from the start of a round?

Comment: I would this is implemented for the running speed bonus. Are you actually so close to the bots that they are trying to stab you during the first 5 seconds?

Comment: This is aim_* map, with short  distance between spawns(~30 meters). Bots run with knifes into the middle of the room before switching to rifles, giving them no chance against my rifle.

Comment: You can prevent bots from using certain weapons, but afaik that doesn't include knives. What you can do is editing the navigation mesh if you're somewhat familiar with it. You can as well edit the bot settings to make them see you from a further distance.

Comment: What is the command to make them see me from further distance?

Comment: Sounds like a navigation issue